# What exactly are addresses and offsets in native crash call stack?

Tags: android, c++, debugging, crash

Whenever there is a crash in my android app native code, I use addr2line tool provided by NDK to resolve the addresses to exact code lines in source code. All these days I was ignoring the other information provided in call stack, i.e. offset. Example crash stack

```
08-16 07:44:47.328  1349  1349 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000000000e52516  /data/data/com.syam.test/files/data/applibs/libnative.so (offset 0x1702000)

08-16 07:44:47.328  1349  1349 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0000000000e5242b  /data/data/com.syam.test/files/data/applibs/libnative.so (offset 0x1702000)

08-16 07:44:47.328  1349  1349 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000000e5226d  /data/data/com.syam.test/files/data/applibs/libnative.so (offset 0x1702000)
```

While thinking about these offsets, I also came to understand that I also dont know what these addresses corresponds to physically..

Could somebody please enlighten me on these two of crash stack i.e. address and offset. What exactly these correspond to and how can I better make use of them.

Answer (score 1):

The offset is simply the start address in the process where that module (*i.e.* shared library) is loaded.  So the actual address in relation to the process itself is `offset + address`.

This is how the OS can identify which module crashed, based only on what address was in the program register at the time.  Note that there's another layer to this at least, because a process itself has its own offset in global address space and can actually be moved around by the OS.  But I digress..

Since the library itself may be loaded anywhere within the process's address space, it's not useful to a developer unless they know the offset too.  Fortunately, you can just subtract the offset and get back to a library-specific address that is determined at compile time.  This is how `addr2line` works.

In other words, the offset can change but the address is fixed.

The point of all this is that you don't need to compile a binary with any debugging symbols included (so someone else can't easily find out how your program works).  But if someone reports a crash and you have at least the process address and the library offset, you can determine where it happened by using privately-held debug symbols.

So, if you have the symbols and source code for `libnative.so` that was used to build the version running at the time your program crashed, then you can use the exact same technique to learn where this occurred.  The library might contain some basic debugging information such as function names, if you're lucky.

Comment: Thanks Paddy!!
with your answer I understand the concept... 
One may need to go through https://groups.google.com/g/android-ndk/c/F1q_qw5MFfU to practically get the benefit.